# choosing a family in glm- non-integer sort of poisson y distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am struggling to find the right family to use in a hierarchal general linear regression. My dependent variables (y) have shapes that may be a bit similar to poisson or gamma families, and the data are non-integer numbers.

Regarding that, I have two questions:

1. should I choose the family based only on the distribution of Y? or, should I choose it based on the distribution of the errors (and if so, how do I find this distribution)?
2. I attach two histograms of the two y variables I want to check. Does anyone know what family and link functions I should specify?

Thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're looking at the marginal distribution  of the response; the model is a model for the conditional distribution. One doesn't necessarily tell you anything of much value about the other. You cannot choose a link function that way either.

Comment: Have you tried transforming the responses (e.g., via the log transform)? If you don't have counts, you shouldn't be considering the Poisson distribution at all. The gamma distribution could be a possibility, but if the logged responses are approximately normally distributed, using a linear model will be much easier (and you can check that the normality assumption is reasonable using standard residual plots).